# on listview click show different-2 activity

Tags: android, listview, position

dear... sir/mam, in my application every list item position has different responce id ..i want to disply toast message of that responce id according to position clicked on it means bundle that response id according to position what to do ...sir i am new in android so describe it with code ..i attach my some code so pls add neccesery code on it...pls pls 
thanks in advance

```
 @Override
    **protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        **String responceid = Activity2.getData();**

        Object o = (String) (Notepadv3.this).getListAdapter().getItem(position);**

        Toast.makeText(this, "this row  responce id is= " + " " + , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
```

Comment: Restricting your possibilities of response from female developers? why sir?

Answer (score 0):

try `Toast.makeText(this, "this row  responce id is= " + responceid  + , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: i have responceid different-2 for each listview  when i click on listview show its own responce id                                String responceid = Activity2.getData();

Answer (score 0):

Have your response in a ArrayList of type String.

```
ArrayList respCode<String> =new Arraylist<String>();
respCode.add("RESPONSE 1");
respCode.add("RESPONSE 2");
```

then in the listview itemClickListner

```
@Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(this,respCode.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Comment: yes the ArrayList is of type string..you can add the string to it